# Good resource for learning braid theory?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, big-list, knot-theory

I recently heard about braid theory and read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_theory) on it, and it seems really beautiful. What is a good resource for learning more about it?

I have a background in mathematics at the undergraduate level—I took introductory courses on combinatorial topology and abstract algebra (I definitely found the latter quite difficult).

Comment: Kassel and Turaev, maybe (http://books.google.com/books/about/Braid_Groups.html?id=y6Cox3XjdroC), although it might be tough going if you found abstract algebra difficult (it is a graduate text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can approach the subject. I personally went via the algebraic topology route which you may find useful if you know something about the fundamental group/manifolds/higher homotopy groups. I wrote a little about a few resources (definitely not exhaustive) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378406/braid-invariants-resource). The first two references are algebraic topology-based. The third, more accessible and elementary, reference only relies on a background in a small amount of group theory and linear algebra.

For your convenience I'll leave those references below:

> J. S. Birman *Braids, Links and Mapping Class Groups*, Annals of Mathematical Studies **82**, Princeton University Press, 1975.
>
> V. L. Hansen, *Braids and Coverings*, London Mathematical Society Student Texts **18**, Cambridge University Press, 1989.
>
> K. Murasugi & B. Kurpita, *A Study of Braids*, Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1999.

Answer (score 1):

There is this nice playlist by  youtuber "Ester Dalvit" on this topic. [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3Gt578803I&list=PLyxHTRWELFBoijzAvXTDOLIF5yfkwN4wZ)